# How to implement only specific method of CrudRepository in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `CrudRepository` of spring-data-jpa to just define an interface of an entity and then having all standard crud methods without having to provide an implementation explicitly, eg:

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Though now I'd like to override only the `save()` method in my custom implementation. How could I achieve this? Because, if I implement the interface `UserRepo`, I'd have to implement all other CRUD methods that are inherited from interface `CrudRepository`.

Can't I write my own implementation that has all CRUD methods but overriding only one without having to implement all others myself?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do something **pretty similar**, which I believe will **achieve the result you're looking for.**

STEPS NECESSARY:

1. `UserRepo` will now extend 2 interfaces:

   ```
    public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserCustomMethods{

    }
   ```
2. Create a new interface named `UserCustomMethods` (you can choose the name and change both here and in step 1)

   ```
    public interface UserCustomMethods{
        public void mySave(User... users);

    }
   ```
3. create a new class named `UserRepoImpl` (here the name **does** matter and it should be RepositoryName**Impl**, because if you call it something else, you will need to adjust the Java/XML configuration accordingly). this class should implement only the **CUSTOM** interface you've created.

**TIP: you can inject entitymanager in this class for your queries**

```
public class UserRepoImpl implements UserRepo {
    
    //This is my tip, but not a must...
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void mySave(User... users){
        //do what you need here
    }
}
```

4. Inject `UserRepo` wherever you need, and enjoy both CRUD and your custom methods :)

Comment: So in order to override only the save method would I declare/implement the save method in the UserCustomMethods/UserRepoImpl?. The example you give here shows an additional method, but does this apply to the existing methods as well?

Comment: Yes, you can add methods to your custom interface with the same signature of the default methods you want to ovverride and implement them your way in the Impl class implementing the custom interface: in this way, Spring Data will use your custom implementation instead of the default one. At least this works for me for the delete method in Spring Data JPA 1.7.2.

Comment: How can I use non custom methods of UserRepo (auto provided by spring data) in UserRepoImpl :) ?

Comment: Does this worksto be exposed as spring-data-rest repository?

Comment: Can I mark the custom mySave() as responding to PUT /user/{id}?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can inject an instance of UserRepo into UserRepoImpl because UserRepoImpl is used by UserRepo so at time of bean creation of UserRepoImpl, UserRepo isn't fully-created/registered yet. At least I found that to be true with spring data starter 2.0.5.RELEASE